# A problem of wait() when using Reentrantlock

Tags: java, multithreading

When I ran this code, I got an error

```
static class PrintUseReentranLock implements Runnable{
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition  = lock.newCondition();
    int n;
    int i;
    public PrintUseReentranLock(int n){
        this.n = n;
        this.i = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(i<n){
            lock.lock();
            condition.signal();
            if(i%2==0)  System.out.println("A");
            else  System.out.println("B");
            i++;
            try {
                condition.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            condition.signal();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
    @Test
    public void test2(){
        PrintUseReentranLock p = new PrintUseReentranLock(10);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:321)
at ConsumerProductor.PrintUseLock$PrintUseReentranLock.run(PrintUseLock.java:96)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

But when I changed the code to this

```
static class PrintUseReentranLock implements Runnable{
        ReentrantLock lock;
        Condition condition;
        int n;
        int i;
        public PrintUseReentranLock(int n){
            this.n = n;
            this.i = 0;
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
            this.condition = lock.newCondition();

        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(i<n){
                lock.lock();
                condition.signal();
                if(i%2==0)  System.out.println("A");
                else  System.out.println("B");
                i++;
                try {
                    condition.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                condition.signal();
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void test2(){
        PrintUseReentranLock p = new PrintUseReentranLock(10);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I new the lock and condition in constructor so it excute successfully. But I don't know why.
It seems like the difference is that new the Reentrantlock and Condition in Class and in Constructor, but I really don't know why they excute diffrently, I think they are almost the same.

Comment: Try using [`condition.await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) instead of [`condition.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) which uses the intrinsic lock (that doesn't come from `Condition`).

Comment: Call `condition.await()`. Not `condition.wait()`. (The `wait()` method is defined for _all_ objects.)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `condition.wait();`, you are calling: [Objects.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), and this call requires :

> The current thread must own this object's monitor.

so you would have to add:

```
synchronized (condition) {
   // ...
   condition.wait()
}
```

and this would be required in both your classes, and would not actually make your class work as expected.

But, what you actually want is to call [Condition.await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--). It does not require `synchronized` as `Objects.wait`.

The problem with your code should still persist in that there is no clear way on how to hand the processing between threads. Usually Condition.await() is called when the thread recognizes that there is no work for it. Below code is  my try at fixing it:

```
static class PrintUseReentranLock2 implements Runnable{
    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition condition;
    int n; //f ds
    int i;

    public PrintUseReentranLock2(int n){
        this.n = n;
        this.i = 0;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.condition = lock.newCondition();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(i<n){
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (Integer.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getName()) != i%2)
                    condition.await();
                if(i%2==0) System.out.println("A");
                else System.out.println("B");
                i++;
                condition.signal();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void test2(){
    PrintUseReentranLock2 p = new PrintUseReentranLock2(10);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(p, "0");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(p, "1");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Now, both threads take turns at processing `i` variable.